# Xamarin iOS Navigate to Settings

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have been trying to find a way to navigate to navigate from an Application to the Settings preferences for the Application.

I have tried the following, yet unfortunately it does error.

> ```
>       var root = new UINavigationController ();
>       root.PushViewController (new Uri ("prefs:root=General"), true);
> ```

When trying this, I did believe it would error as it should be used to Navigate to an already made view.

Is there anyway I am able to navigate to the settings application as required via the use of Xamarin C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, you can't. Apple disabled the ability to do this in iOS 5.1.

The only option is creating your own preferences UI and displaying that instead.

---

**Edit:** as of iOS 8, you can take the user direct to your app's preferences:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is working in iPhone.

```
var url = new NSUrl("prefs:root=Settings");
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
```

Comment: Apple may reject your app for using that. It's a private URL scheme - [source](https://gist.github.com/phynet/471089a51b8f940f0fb4#gistcomment-1825905)